# How can I instantiate C++ class A in the constructor of class B such that its object is available to the member functions

Tags: c++, arduino, inner-classes

Most of my background is in Python and I am trying to re-learn C++ as it applies to micro-controller boards like Arduino.

I have created a standalone C++ class named `DigitalGPIOPin`.  I also have another class named `DigitalRGBPin` that will need to instantiate 3 objects of the `DigitalGPIOPin` class in the constructor and share access to the objects with its member functions.  Is this possible with C++?

I am attaching my attempt at this problem thus far with a simplified case, but I get the error shown below the code, which indicates that the member function `initialize_rgb_pin()` can not access the objects.

```
// GPIOPin.hpp file
class DigitalGPIOPin
{
public:
    int id;  // Pin identifier
    int io   // INPUT or OUTPUT
    DigitalGPIOPin(int identifier, int io_type);
    void initialize_pin();
};
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

class DigitalRGBPin
{
public:
    int red_id, green_id, blue_id
    DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier);
    void initialize_rgb_pin();
};
// =================================================================
// =================================================================

// GPIOPin.cpp file
DigitalGPIOPin::DigitalGPIOPin(int identifier, int io_type)
{
    id = identifier;
    io = io_type;
}

void
DigitalGPIOPin::initialize_pin()
{
    if (io == OUTPUT || io == INPUT || io == INPUT_PULLUP) {
        pinMode(id, io);
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Pin mode not recognized");
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

DigitalRGBPin::DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier)
{
    red_id = red_identifier;
    green_id = green_identifier;
    blue_id = blue_identifier;
    DigitalGPIOPin red_pin(red_identifier, OUTPUT);
    DigitalGPIOPin green_pin(green_identifier, OUTPUT);
    DigitalGPIOPin blue_pin(blue_identifier, OUTPUT);
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

void
DigitalRGBPin::initialize_rgb_pin()
{
    red_pin.initialize_pin();
    /* Commented out lines below to focus on problem.
       The compiler does not recognize red_pin, because it
       was not defined as a public variable.  So how can I
       define this without having to re-write the entire
       DigitalGPIOPin class as a nested class within DigitalRGBPin.
       This would effectively put me in a position where I have to define
       the class twice, since I still need it as a standalone class. 
    */
    // green_pin.initialize_pin();
    // blue_pin.initialize_pin();
}
```

This yields the following error:

> `error: red_pin was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `red_pin`, `green_pin`, and `blue_pin` as **local variables** inside of your `DigitalRGBPin()` constructor.  As such, the compiler error is correct - they are not in scope for `initialize_rgb_pin()` (or any other method of `DigitalRGBPin`) to access.

You need to make them be members of the `DigitalRGBPin` class (just as you did for `id` and `io` in  the `DigitalGPIOPin` class, and `red_id`, `green_id`, `blue_id` in the `DigitalRGBPin` class).

However, you will have to use the `DigitalRGBPin()` constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to initialize them <sup>1</sup>, since `DigitalGPIOPin` doesn't have a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) defined.

<sup>1: you should get in the habit of using the member initialization list for all of your classes when it is feasible to do so.</sup>

Try this:

GPIOPin.hpp

```cpp
class DigitalGPIOPin
{
public:
    int id;  // Pin identifier
    int io;  // INPUT or OUTPUT
    DigitalGPIOPin(int identifier, int io_type);
    void initialize_pin();
};
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    
class DigitalRGBPin
{
public:
    int red_id, green_id, blue_id;
    DigitalGPIOPin red_pin, green_pin, blue_pin;
    DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier);
    void initialize_rgb_pin();
};
// =================================================================
// =================================================================
```

GPIOPin.cpp

```cpp
DigitalGPIOPin::DigitalGPIOPin(int identifier, int io_type) :
    id(identifier),
    io(io_type)
{
}

void DigitalGPIOPin::initialize_pin()
{
    if (io == OUTPUT || io == INPUT || io == INPUT_PULLUP) {
        pinMode(id, io);
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Pin mode not recognized");
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    
DigitalRGBPin::DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier) :
    red_id(red_identifier),
    green_id(green_identifier),
    blue_id(blue_identifier),
    red_pin(red_identifier, OUTPUT),
    green_pin(green_identifier, OUTPUT),
    blue_pin(blue_identifier, OUTPUT)
{
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

void DigitalRGBPin::initialize_rgb_pin()
{
    red_pin.initialize_pin();
    green_pin.initialize_pin();
    blue_pin.initialize_pin();
}
```

---

On a side note, the `red_id`, `green_id`, and `blue_id` members of the `DigitalRGBPin` class are redundant, and thus can (and should) be removed in favor of using `red_pin.id`, `green_pin.id`, and `blue_pin.id` when needed, eg:

GPIOPin.hpp

```cpp
class DigitalGPIOPin
{
public:
    int id;  // Pin identifier
    int io;  // INPUT or OUTPUT
    DigitalGPIOPin(int identifier, int io_type);
    void initialize_pin();
};
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    
class DigitalRGBPin
{
public:
    DigitalGPIOPin red_pin, green_pin, blue_pin;
    DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier);
    void initialize_rgb_pin();
};
// =================================================================
// =================================================================
```

GPIOPin.cpp

```cpp
DigitalGPIOPin::DigitalGPIOPin(int identifier, int io_type) :
    id(identifier),
    io(io_type)
{
}

void DigitalGPIOPin::initialize_pin()
{
    if (io == OUTPUT || io == INPUT || io == INPUT_PULLUP) {
        pinMode(id, io);
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Pin mode not recognized");
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
    
DigitalRGBPin::DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier) :
    red_pin(red_identifier, OUTPUT),
    green_pin(green_identifier, OUTPUT),
    blue_pin(blue_identifier, OUTPUT)
{
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

void DigitalRGBPin::initialize_rgb_pin()
{
    red_pin.initialize_pin();
    green_pin.initialize_pin();
    blue_pin.initialize_pin();
}
```

Comment: Somewhat more complete than the other answer but I would also recommand to make `initialize_pin` private and call it from the constructor of that class and then remove `initialize_rgb_pin` unless there is a good reason to have separate steps.

Comment: @Phil1970 Without knowing how `DigitalRGBPin` is actually being used, I would not presume to recommend whether `initialize_rgb_pin()` should be removed or not. We don't know what other dependancies/initializations may have to be performed before `initialize_pin()` can be called.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, that was a thorough example.  When I last had any semblance of C++ knowledge was long before C++11.  IN the version of C++ that I last knew, I do not believe you could initialize variables in the constructor in the way you showed here.  I am not sure if this is new, or if I never knew this method.  Regardless, it was a great teaching moment for me, thank you.

Comment: @Jon use of a constructor's member initialization list predates C++11 by a long time

Comment: That is interesting. I just went through my college text book on C++ which has three chapters on classes and nowhere does it show an example or teach the method you showed me in this post.

Comment: @Jon you didn't say which version of C++ that book teaches, but the member initialization list certainly existed in C++98, at least.

Comment: I dont doubt you! I just wonder how such an important syntax was omitted from a text book and collegiate syllabus.

Comment: @Jon well, that's easy - because many colleges don't teach C++ properly. We see it all the time on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want your three `DigitalGPIOPin` objects to be declared as member-variables of your `DigitalRGBPin` class, and initialized as part of the constructor's initializer-list, like this:

```
class DigitalRGBPin
{
public:
    int red_id, green_id, blue_id;
    DigitalGPIOPin red_pin;
    DigitalGPIOPin green_pi;
    DigitalGPIOPin blue_pin;

    DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier);
    void initialize_rgb_pin();
};
// =================================================================
// =================================================================

DigitalRGBPin::DigitalRGBPin(int red_identifier, int green_identifier, int blue_identifier)
    : red_pin(red_identifier, OUTPUT)
    , green_pin(green_identifier, OUTPUT)
    , blue_pin(blue_identifier, OUTPUT)
{
    red_id = red_identifier;
    green_id = green_identifier;
    blue_id = blue_identifier;
}
```

(You might want to move the initialization of `red_id`, `green_id`, and `blue_id` up into the initializer-list as well, for consistency, but it's not required)

Comment: It is then useless to have `int red_id, green_id, blue_id;` and `void initialize_rgb_pin();`.

Comment: @Phil1970 I agree that `red_id` etc are redundant and should be removed in favor of using `red_pin.id` etc instead.  But, `initialize_rgb_pin()` is hardly useless, since the 3 pins still be to be initialized individually via `DigitalGPIOPin::initialize_pin()`, and we don't have enough info to know if that is safe to do inside the constructor.